# Can't center div properly

Tags: html, css

This is a problem I had a lot of trouble with: I can't center my divs properly on my webpage. The situation is as follows: the div I'm trying to center is in another div. After a lot of research and hundreds of ways that failed, I managed to center it. However, when I then make the viewport smaller than the div, it suddenly doesn't center anymore and floats to the left. I only have this problem with unordered lists (navigations) in divs.

Here is the code of my webpage (simplified) and on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ahOkepaw/1/edit?html,css,output):

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header id="topheader">
            ...
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            ...
            <div id="images">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            ...

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The problem is with the images div. There is also a similar thing somewhere else on the page.

My question is: why is it doing this, and how can it be solved?

Comment: Can you create a minimum sample on www.jsbin.com or www.jsfiddle.com with the part of your css that doesn't work. Also paste the css for your div#content container

Comment: also div#container and <header> please

Comment: use __margin:0 auto;__ to center any element

Comment: Make sure to include your html as well, as it is hard to guess where your middle_content_images element is located

Comment: In your example the css is not related to the html you showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:0 auto;` center's the div, not the content....what i mean to say is, that if your `div` is `60px` wide and content is only `30px` wide, then the div will align to center but the content will still `align` to one-side of the div, not in the center, giving a view that div is not centered.....my suggestion is to use `text-align` property too with `margin`

see this  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5A2s7/)  and notice the `border` to understand that the div is centerd....but content is not~

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width:98%;
    margin:0 auto;/*center div*/
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#images {
    width:98%;
    margin:0 auto;/*center div*/
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    text-align:center /*center text*/
}
```